# Finding ratio of group by factors in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I want to calculate  the ratio  of the following case. any optimal code for doing the below scenario in Python. I am not able figure out in Python but able do the same in R.

**Input**

```
Ord_ID  Flag
48221742    Y
48221742    Y
48221742    Y
48221742    Y
48221742    N
48221742    N
48221742    Y
48221742    N
48221742    N
48221742    N
291000002   N
291000002   Y
291000002   Y
291000002   Y
291000002   N
291000002   N
291000002   N
291000002   N
```

**Output**

```
Ord_ID  Flag    Y_Flag_Ratio
48221742    Y   0.5
48221742    Y   0.5
48221742    Y   0.5
48221742    Y   0.5
48221742    N   0.5
48221742    N   0.5
48221742    Y   0.5
48221742    N   0.5
48221742    N   0.5
48221742    N   0.5
291000002   N   0.375
291000002   Y   0.375
291000002   Y   0.375
291000002   Y   0.375
291000002   N   0.375
291000002   N   0.375
291000002   N   0.375
291000002   N   0.375
```

I tried the same in R, I was able to do the same in  a single line code.

```
Data$Y_flag_ratio = ave(Data$Flag == "Y", Data$Ord_ID)
```

Comment: have you tried anything in python for the same?

Comment: @chakri,any optimal code in python

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner, but

```
ratio = (
    df[df.Flag == 'Y'].groupby(['Ord_ID']).count() /
    df.groupby(['Ord_ID']).count()
).rename(columns={'Flag': 'Y_Flag_Ratio'})

print(pd.concat([df, ratio], axis=1))
```

---

If you only want a ratio for given id, then it acually can be one-liner.

```
>>> (df[df.Ord_ID == 291000002].Flag == 'Y').mean()
0.375
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ord_ID_total=data.groupby(['Ord_ID']).agg({'Ord_ID': 'count'})
Ord_ID_Y=data[data['Flag'] == 'Y'].groupby(['Ord_ID']).agg({'Ord_ID': 'count'})

def computeFlag(Ord_ID):
    Y_Flag_Ratio=0

    try:
        Y_Flag_Ratio=Ord_ID_Y.Ord_ID[Ord_ID]/Ord_ID_total.Ord_ID[Ord_ID]
    except:
        pass
```